# Overwriting a passed on function from a parent class

Tags: python, class, abstract-class, parent-child

Hey my task is to create a parentclass Shape and pass the functions on to the different shapes. Since a Circlearea calculation takes different parameters I am trying to overwrite the function. It throws following warning: "Signature of method 'Circel.get_area()' does not match Signature in the base method in Shape". Is that possible at all? How would I have to do it? Should it work anyway later on?

```
class Shape(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def get_area(self, x_l, y_l):
        pass

    def move(self, newx, newy):
        pass

class Circle(Shape):

    def __init__(self, rad, x_pos, y_pos):
        self.rad = rad
        self.pos = (x_pos, y_pos)
        self.area = self.get_area(self, self.rad)
    
    def get_area(self, rad):
        return(self.rad*self.rad*2*m.pi)
```

Comment: Why would you be passing the radius to a circle instance's `get_area` method? Surely a circle should know its own radius. (That is, it should be stored as an instance attribute, exactly as you have done.) A `get_area` method probably should not need any parameters in any shape.

Comment: In fact, `get_area` ignores its `rad` argument and uses `self.rad` anyway.

Comment: Unrelated, you should not be changing the signature of `get_area` between the parent and the child. `def get_area(self): ...` in both.

Comment: `self.area = self.get_area(self, self.rad)` you don't pass the `self` arg to the method yourself when calling it, Python does that automatically. Combined with suggestion from other comments this should just be `self.area = self.get_area()`